# Error in building mean image file(Caffe)

Tags: classification, deep-learning, caffe, mnist

I am trying to do classification of digits(mnist). I need to make an mean image file from the lmdb data to use it for testing(classification) on an image of a digit.
So I am trying to use the compute_image_mean to build the mean image file but I am getting the following error below.

```
F1219 12:45:42.852679  6189 db_lmdb.hpp:15] Check failed: mdb_status == 0 (20 vs. 0) Not a directory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
@     0x7f4c092bbdaa  (unknown)
@     0x7f4c092bbce4  (unknown)
@     0x7f4c092bb6e6  (unknown)
@     0x7f4c092be687  (unknown)
@     0x7f4c097a1291  caffe::db::LMDB::Open()
@           0x402044  main
@     0x7f4c082c7f45  (unknown)
@           0x402a8a  (unknown)
@              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Command used- ./../build/tools/compute_image_mean ./data/train.mdb ./mean.binaryproto

Is this the correct way to generate a mean image file?

[caffe users group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/3ORwBhspUJM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DB path you only need to supply the path to the DB folder, and not the db itself.
Try:

```
 ./../build/tools/compute_image_mean ./data/ ./mean.binaryproto
```

Comment: Hi Shai, I did that but I still got the same error. Do check out the caffe users link in the question where the question has progressed further.

Comment: @KevinGeorge I saw the link you posted. The error you get clearly states that caffe cannot find your db file. try using absolute paths for `train.mdb`'s folder

Comment: As you can see in the script,'make_mnist_mean' I used absolute paths but the error is still there.

Comment: @KevinGeorge what is the output of `ls ./data/`? does `train.mdb` exists there? do you have read permission to the lmdb folder? is it possible the db is corrupted?

Comment: yes I think it was a problem with the db. I remade it and the error went away. Thanks a lot Shai for the help.